# List available stack build plans

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, stackage

How can I get the list of available build plans for stack? On some system I get `lts-3.7` and some other I have `lts-3.1`.

Comment: Do you mean a shell command? Do you use `cabal`? Please provide more information.

Comment: He uses `stack`/Stackage, as mentioned quite obviously.

Comment: By the way, the default resolver for when you run `stack` outside a project, and the preferred resolver for `stack new` and `stack init`, is set in `~/.stack/global/stack.yaml`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A list of all available snapshots is at https://www.stackage.org/snapshots.  Stackage.org builds this list from the build plans in these repositories:

- https://github.com/fpco/lts-haskell (for `lts-M.N` snapshots)
- https://github.com/fpco/stackage-nightly (for `nightly-YYYY-MM-DD` snapshots)

Comment: is there a way to get that on the cmdline? or is it always the same and not dependent on the machine?

Comment: It isn't the full information, but this will give you back some JSON showing the latest nightly, and latest minor version for every major LTS release:
`curl -sSL http://www.stackage.org/download/lts-snapshots.json`

Comment: Is there also a way to get a list of available resolvers?

Comment: I don't believe that there is.  You can submit a feature request at https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/new